# Change colour of Picker within NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to embed this NavigationView within a larger view but nothing I seem to set will change to background colour of the Picker within this view.

When I do the following, everything other than the Picker itself is set to black, but the picker remains white, like so...

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUoty.png)

There may be a much better setup to get the effect I am after but not knowing that, how do I change the Picker Colour also?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var value = ""

    init(){
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.black
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                Form {
                    Picker(selection: $value, label: Text("This")) {
                        Text("1").tag("1")
                        Text("2").tag("2")
                        Text("3").tag("3")
                        Text("4").tag("4")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`listRowBackground`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/listrowbackground(_:)) for that.

```swift
Picker(selection: $value, label: Text("this")) {
  ...
}.listRowBackground(Color.green)
```

---

---

---

In order to change the background color of the cells in the opened picker, you'll have to set them through UIKit.

```
extension View {
  func cellBackgroundColor(_ uiColor: UIColor) -> some View {
    background(TableCellGrabber { cell in
      cell.backgroundView = UIView()
      cell.backgroundColor = uiColor
    })
  }
}

struct TableCellGrabber: UIViewRepresentable {
  let configure: (UITableViewCell) -> Void
  
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    UIView()
  }
  
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if let cell: UITableViewCell = uiView.parentView() {
        configure(cell)
      }
    }
  }
}

extension UIView {
  func parentView<T: UIView>() -> T? {
    if let v = self as? T {
      return v
    }
    
    return superview?.parentView()
  }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
Picker(selection: $value, label: Text("this")) {
  Text("1").tag("1").cellBackgroundColor(.red)
  Text("2").tag("2").cellBackgroundColor(.red)
  Text("3").tag("3").cellBackgroundColor(.red)
  Text("4").tag("4").cellBackgroundColor(.red)
}
```

Or you can use special `Group` view to apply it to all grouped items.

```swift
Picker(selection: $value, label: Text("this")) {
  Group {
    Text("1").tag("1")
    Text("2").tag("2")
    Text("3").tag("3")
    Text("4").tag("4")
  }.cellBackgroundColor(.red)
}
```

Comment: when I click into the picker - the options 1-4 are all white still - is there a different option to set those?

Comment: There isn't any easy way

Comment: @AlexJ Updated my answer for that. You can grab `UITableView` and configure it the same way if needed